# Regarding Hashing - Quadratic Probing Proof

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I was looking into the collision resolution methods for hashing, especially in open addressing (eg. linear probing, quadratic probing). Linear probing is easy to understand because it refers something like,

```
index = hash(value)
for i, 0 -> SIZE
   seek_index = (index + i) % SIZE
   if map[seek_index] is EMPTY
      //proceed insertion
```

But for Quadratic probing I wonder until when I need to search the empty slot?

```
index = hash(value)
for i, 0 -> SIZE    // Is it should be up to SIZE ?
   seek_index = (index + i*i) % SIZE
   if map[seek_index] is EMPTY
      //proceed insertion
```

If the limit is SIZE or anything else whats the proof that I will get the EMPTY cell if there in map?

Any reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee you'll probe every element in the array.

For example, consider `SIZE=5`. Then you'll probe (relative to `index`) at indexes 0, 1², 2², 3², 4², which (modulo 5) are 0, 1, 4, 4, 1. So if the empty spaces are at indexes 2 or 3 (relative to `index`), then you'll not find them.

Squares mod n are called "quadratic residues", [and the number of quadratic residues modulo n cannot exceed n/2 + 1 (n even) or (n + 1)/2 (n odd).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#History,_conventions,_and_elementary_facts)

Comment: So why do we use quadratic probing? It seems spaces will be wasted and also there will be chance of missing keys. What am I missing? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's a different question to the one you asked, but the wikipedia page on quadratic hashing seems to answer it towards the bottom.